# aws-cli --query parameter

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, aws-security-group

I am trying to do a filter using aws query to output 0.0.0.0/0 Ips and find which ports they are coming from however when I do

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=ip-permission.cidr,Values='0.0.0.0/0' --query "SecurityGroups[*].{GN:GroupName,Ports: IpPermissions.FromPorts}" --output json
```

In the Ports column, it outputs None, since it is not finding that filter and when I do

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=ip-permission.cidr,Values='0.0.0.0/0' --query "SecurityGroups[*].{GN:GroupName,Ports: IpPermissions}" --output json
```

I get all the Ip Ranges when I only want ***0.0.0.0/0 and which Port that Open Ip is coming from (FromPort and ToPort***). And I don't want to do a filter just for a certain Port because I want to see what port each open Ip is coming from.

I am not sure why this is not working since the IpPermissions.ToPort and IpPermissions.FromPort are both a filter of aws security groups.

Answer (score 0):

You need two modification in the query

- The key name is `FromPort` not `FromPort`
- IpPermissions return array not object, so use `IpPermissions[].FromPort`

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=ip-permission.cidr,Values='0.0.0.0/0' \
--query "SecurityGroups[*].{GN:GroupName,Ports: IpPermissions[].FromPort}" --output json
```